# Email template in salesforce

Tags: email-template

can we embed a jpeg into an HTML email rather than attaching it? in email templates if we can embed may i know the possibility please

Answer (score 0):

You can include images or logos on your HTML and Visualforce email templates. For HTML with letterhead templates, logos or images come from the letterhead you choose when creating the template.

When creating custom HTML or Visualforce templates, simply include img tags that reference the image. We recommend uploading the images to the Documents tab and referencing the copy of the image on the Salesforce server.

For example, for HTML:

```
 <img src="https://c.<instance>.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=<document_id>&oid=<organization_id>"  alt="Company Logo" 
height="64" width="64"/>
```

Check [Adding Images to Email Templates](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_template_images.htm)

**Note**:  Images should be stored in documents and with "Externally Available Image" checked